# Is there any way to save application data evenif anyone delete the ipa?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, plist, nsuserdefaults

I working on a eBook-reader application. Here if user downloads any book than i need to save that book outside application directory.

currently i am saving within application directory. That's why after updating the application with new ipa, downloaded data also removed.

Is there (iOS) anything like content provider in Android.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, After updating the app the contents of document directory stays there and are not deleted.
This would be happen if you delete the existing app from device and installs the new one. When app is upgraded with new version in practical scenario, you will not loose any data that is currently in the application's document directory.

Secondly, if you dont want any data lost in either of the cases, I would suggest to implement iCloud. There you can sync your data which you want to fetch at later stages in the app.

best of luck!!